# Is it possible to grant multiple users to Jupyter notebook?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, jupyter-notebook

I am working on a project in an EC2 isntance using jupyter notebook. It seems like jupyter notebook does not allow multiple ssh to its server at the same time, I have to log out if other people want to connect to jupyter notebook through the instance. Is it possible to make multiple access to jupyter notebook from the same instance?

Comment: what do you mean it doesn't allow? what happens when you try

Comment: @maxymoo the other users cannot connect to my server if I am already logged in, the link provided by jupyter notebook for other users would give a blank page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The juypter notebook is installed on a server in this case an EC2 machine.
Any number of people can SSH into this machine if they have the credentials using putty or some ssh client, this has no connection with jupyter notebook.

(assuming that the SSH port 22 is open for the other users and they are able to connect)

When you launch the jupyter notebook using the `jupyter notebook` command -> you start a local instance of the jupyter notebook on the default port (maybe 8888)

you will have a URL for this notebook interface and you can work on it. 
Important to note -> This is a local instance of your notebook. It is not public and can only be accessed on your OS username as a localhost.

If other OS users run the `jupyter notebook` command they will get their local version of the notebook on a different port (maybe 8889 by default as the port number 8888 is already in use by you )

You can make your notebook [public](http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/public_server.html) and then you will get a public URL for your notebook (serverip:8888 or the port you have specified)

This public link can be shared with others. Now multiple people have visibility to your notebook and can edit code in your notebook.

p.s -> for public notebooks the port in which you are running the notebook needs to accept connections from AWS end. This can be configured in AWS console under the security groups tab

Answer (score 2):

Create/update `jupyter_notebook_config.py` file in `~/.jupyter` folder with the below code. All `jupyter notebook` command calls post this file creation will infer configuration from the file.

```
from notebook.auth import passwd

c = get_config()
c.NotebookApp.open_browser=False
c.NotebookApp.ip='*' # Allows access from anywhere
c.NotebookApp.port=8885 # Jupyter runs in port 8885
c.NotebookApp.password=passwd('jupyter') # Password to access notebooks
```

Make sure you've opened 8885 (or any other port of your choice mentioned in the configuration file) allows connection requests from outside (update EC2 security groups appropriately). Not sure if you've tried this or what the issue at your end is but this works for me.