# multiuser public jupyter notebook on AWS sagemaker

Tags: amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook, amazon-sagemaker

I know there is a good tutorial on how to create jupyter notebooks on AWS sagemaker "the easy way".

Do you know if it is possible to allow 10 students to create jupyter-notebooks who do not have an AWS accounts, and also allow them to edit jupyter-notebooks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enabling multiple users to leverage the same notebook (in this case, without authentication) will involve managing your Security Groups to enable open access. You can filter, allowing access for a known IP address range, if your students are accessing it from a classroom or campus, for example.

Tips for this are available in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42617692/is-it-possible-to-grant-multiple-users-to-jupyter-notebook) and this page from the documentation, diving into [network configurations for SageMaker hosted notebook instances](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/understanding-amazon-sagemaker-notebook-instance-networking-configurations-and-advanced-routing-options/).

As for enabling students to spin up their own notebooks, I'm not sure if it's possible to enable completely unauthenticated AWS-level resource provisioning -- however once you've spun up a single managed notebook instance yourself, students can create their own notebooks directly from the browser in Jupyter, once they've navigated to the publicly available IP. You may need to attach a new SageMaker IAM role that enables notebook creation (amongst other things, depending on the workload requirements). Depending on the computational needs (number, duration, and types of concurrent workloads), there will be different optimal setups of number of managed instances and instance type to prevent computational bottlenecking.